# Formate a table with two lines in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hello I have a dataframe such as

```
Start End Feature Qualifier Function
1     35  CDS     Product   Gene1
36    67  CDS     Product   Putative_actin
69    123 CDS     Product   1_hypothetical protein
345   562 CDS     Product   2_hypothetical protein
```

And I would like to format this table as so :

**Line1:**

- Column 1: Start
- Column 2: End
- Column 3: Feature

**Line2:**

- Column 4: Qualifier
- Column 5: Function

and each separate by the ">Feature `Seq_number_of_the_row`"

At the end for this example, I should get :

```
>Feature Seq1
1     35  CDS
              Product   Gene1
>Feature Seq2
36    67  CDS     
              Product   Putative_actin
>Feature Seq3
69    123 CDS
              Product   1_hypothetical protein
>Feature Seq4
345   562 CDS 
              Product   2_hypothetical protein
```

Each column should be separated by a tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With tabulation:

```
for idx, (_, row) in enumerate(df.iterrows(), 1):
    print(f'>Feature Seq{idx}')
    print(f'\t{row.Start}\t{row.End}\t{row.Feature}')
    print(f'\t\t\t\t{row.Qualifier}\t{row.Function}')

# Output
>Feature Seq1
    1   35  CDS
                Product Gene1
>Feature Seq2
    36  67  CDS
                Product Putative_actin
>Feature Seq3
    69  123 CDS
                Product 1_hypothetical protein
>Feature Seq4
    345 562 CDS
                Product 2_hypothetical protein
```

You can use:

```
for idx, (_, row) in enumerate(df.iterrows(), 1):
    print(f'>Feature Seq{idx}')
    print(f'{row.Start:<5}{row.End:<5}{row.Feature}')
    print(f'{"":15}{row.Qualifier:<15}{row.Function}')

# Output

>Feature Seq1
1    35   CDS
               Product        Gene1
>Feature Seq2
36   67   CDS
               Product        Putative_actin
>Feature Seq3
69   123  CDS
               Product        1_hypothetical protein
>Feature Seq4
345  562  CDS
               Product        2_hypothetical protein
```

Comment: If I were the OP, I woud choose the *string alignment* approach, +1 ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this :

```
print(*[f">Feature Seq{i}\n{s}\t{e}\t{f}\n\t\t\t{q}\t{f}"
        for i, (s, e, f, q, f) in enumerate(
            zip(*[df[col] for col in df.columns]), start=1)], sep="\n")
```

Output :

```
>Feature Seq1
1   35  CDS
            Product Gene1
>Feature Seq2
36  67  CDS
            Product Putative_actin
>Feature Seq3
69  123 CDS
            Product 1_hypothetical protein
>Feature Seq4
345 562 CDS
            Product 2_hypothetical protein
```

Answer (score 1):

You could concat the dataframe to itself and format as needed:

```
table = pd.concat([df,df]).sort_index()
table.iloc[::2,3:] = None
table.iloc[1::2,:3] = None

>>> table
   Start    End Feature Qualifier                Function
0    1.0   35.0     CDS      None                    None
0    NaN    NaN    None   Product                   Gene1
1   36.0   67.0     CDS      None                    None
1    NaN    NaN    None   Product          Putative_actin
2   69.0  123.0     CDS      None                    None
2    NaN    NaN    None   Product  1_hypothetical protein
3  345.0  562.0     CDS      None                    None
3    NaN    NaN    None   Product  2_hypothetical protein
```